# how to pull elseif - preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, if-statement, preg-match-all

I need advise how to pull content from this string.

```
$string = "{elseif "xxx"=="xxx"} text {elseif "xx2"!="xx2"}
text text
text
{elseif ....} text";
//or 'xxx'=='xxx'

$regex = "??";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($out);
```

And my idea of ​​var_dump output is:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'xxx' (length=3)
      1 => string '==' (length=2)
      2 => string 'xxx' (length=3)
      3 => string 'text' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array
      1 => string 'xx2' (length=)
      2 => string '!=' (length=)
      3 => string 'xx2' (length=)
      4 => string 'text text
text' (length=)
  2 => 
    array
      ...
```

The output need not necessarily be as follows, but the same content.

my attempt:

```
$regex = "~{elseif ([\"\'](.*)[\"\'])(!=|==|===|<=|<|>=|>)([\"\'](.*)[\"\'])}(.*)~sU";
```

But I have bad or no output content.

Comment: Do you have any attempts yet?

Comment: Now you just told us about a partial/secondary problem of yours, and the wrong tool (which you have no experience in) you sought out to solve it. Elaborate more on context and prior attempts.

Comment: You are going to run into one heck of a headache with parsing like this. For example, you will eventually try to nest an `{if}` statement and it won't work. You will eventually try to use variables which won't work. You will eventually need to check more than one value which won't work. It is just a headache waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? [If you want to test it](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%5C%7B%5Cs%2aelseif%5Cs%2a%28%5C%22%5B%5E%22%5D%2b%5C%22%29%5Cs%2a%28%5B%5E%22%5D%2b%29%5Cs%2a%28%5C%22%5B%5E%22%5D%2b%5C%22%29%5Cs%2a%5C%7D%5Cs%2a%28%5B%5E%7B%5D%2a%29%5Cs%2a&input=%7Belseif%20%22xxx%22==%22xxx%22%7D%20text%20%7Belseif%20%22xx2%22!=%22xx2%22%7D%0Atext%20text%0Atext%0A%7Belseif%20%22xxxxx%22!=%22yyy%22%7D%20text).

```php
$regex = "/\{\s*elseif\s*(\"[^"]+\")\s*([^"]+)\s*(\"[^"]+\")\s*\}\s*([^{]*)\s*/gi";
```